# Error de Flutter

Tags: flutter

Hola soy nueva en Flutter, para la instalacion del SDK de Flutter lo realice con snap y se instalo correctamente pero al buscar el PATH o solamente de presionar Flutter en my shell me sale el siguiente error[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cualquier sugerencia seria de mucha ayuda

Comment: Bienvenida a [es.so], te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. Tu pregunta es demasiado amplia, lo cual hace muy difícil encontrar el problema y darte una solución. Saludos

Comment: Intenta con el comando `which flutter`

Comment: Una manera de instalar el SDK de flutter si llegaras a tener más inconvenientes es descargando el Android srudio y luego instalarlo ahi. Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

En el siguiente enlace he encontrado una persona con el mismo caso:

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/27076

Mencionan el hecho de actualizar el path

```
See (depending on your OS)
https://flutter.io/docs/get-started/install/windows#update-your-path
https://flutter.io/docs/get-started/install/macos#update-your-path
https://flutter.io/docs/get-started/install/linux#update-your-path
```

También mencionan el hecho de que se haya descargado una versión de Flutter que no corresponde al S.O.

> This error occurs if you download and unzip the WINDOWS version into MAC or UNIX!
>
> Please make sure you have download for the RIGHT operating system!